# Php echoing only last post from array and update it only

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

This is my update script of wall page. If a user reply any comment, the update script update yet to all users wall page without refresh. ( just like chat )

So for do this, I need to sent two type id to server.php page, 1st is user page id and 2nd for all post id of user. I create a array for sent all post ids with javascript in wall.php page and another array in server.php to get them.

All array works well, if I test it by `print_r($_REQUEST['CID']); exit;` at server.php page.

But when I reply any post in user page, the update script working only for **last post** not for any others post. *Where is my problem here please?*

my wall.php

```
    // id is dynamic
<div class="case" data-post-id="111"></div> 
<div class="case" data-post-id="222"></div>
<div class="case" data-post-id="333"></div>

//Check for any update after 15 second interval by post id.
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

var CID = [];
$('div[data-post-id]').each(function(i){
    CID[i] = $(this).data('post-id');
});

function addrep(type, msg){
CID.forEach(function(id){
    $("#newreply"+id).append("<div class='"+ type +""+ msg.id +"'><ul>"+ msg.detail +"</ul></div>");
});
}
var tutid = '<?php echo $tutid; ?>';
function waitForRep(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/server.php",
        cache: false,
        data: {
        tutid : tutid,
        CID : CID
    },
        timeout:15000, 
        success: function(data){ 
            addrep("postreply", data);
            setTimeout(
                waitForRep, 
                15000 
            );
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
            setTimeout(
                waitForRep, 
                15000); 
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    waitForRep();
});
</script>
```

server.php

```
while (true) {
if($_REQUEST['tutid'] && $_REQUEST['CID']){
foreach($_REQUEST['CID'] as $key => $value){

date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Dhaka');
$datetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-15 second'));
$res = mysqli_query($dbh,"SELECT * FROM comments_reply WHERE post_id =".$value." AND qazi_id=".$_REQUEST['tutid']."  AND date >= '$datetime' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1") or die(mysqli_error($dbh));

} // array close

$rows =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);  

        $row[] = array_map('utf8_encode', $rows);

        $data = array();

$data['id'] = $rows['id']; 
$data['qazi_id'] = $rows['qazi_id'];
//ect all

// do something and echo $data['detail'] = $detail;

    if (!empty($data)) {
        echo json_encode($data);
        flush();
        exit(0);
    }

}  // request close
sleep(5);
}  // while close
```